# jQuery: beforeShowDay date format issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jQuery ui datepicker in combination with the isotope plugin and filter feature to filter out divs by date. For this filter feature to work the date has been converted to a string and stipped out all the zeros, e.g. `20/08/2013` would read as `2082013`. I'm also using the `beforeShowDay` feature to highlight the relevant dates in the date picker, this is where the problem lies, in my example below as I'm using this date format `1782013 1882013 1982013` is also styling `01/08/2013` etc (as you can see in the fiddle).
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/jPzK2/1/ 
jQuery:

```
var $container = $('#block-wrap');
var $blocks = $("div.blocks", "#block-wrap");

$(function () {
    var blocks = $('#block-wrap .blocks')
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        //nextText: '&rarr;',
        //prevText: '&larr;',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        //dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
        //showOn: "button",
        //buttonImage: "img/calendar-blue.png",
        //buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = new Date(dateText);
            var dateValue = date.getDate().toString() + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getFullYear().toString();

            $container.isotope({
                filter: '[data-value~="' + dateValue + '"]'
            });
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            var target = date.getDate().toString() + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getFullYear().toString();
            var contains = blocks.filter('[data-value*="' + target + '"]').length > 0;
            return [true, contains ? 'special' : '', '']
        }
    });
});

$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.blocks',
        animationEngine: 'css',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 5
        }
    });
});

var prepareData = function (howLong) {
    var mode = howLong,
        date = new Date(),
        days = 0,
        d = date.getDate(),
        m = date.getMonth(),
        y = date.getFullYear(),
        duration = [],
        durationReady = [];

    if (mode === "week") {
        days = 7;
    } else if (mode === "month") {
        days = 30;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        // for each day create date objects in an array
        duration[i] = new Date(y, m, d + i);

        // convert objects into strings
        // fe. 25th of May becomes '2552013'
        durationReady[i] = duration[i].getDate().toString() + (duration[i].getMonth() + 1).toString() + duration[i].getFullYear().toString();

        // 1. select all items which contain given date
        var $applyMarkers = $('.blocks[data-value~="' + durationReady[i] + '"]')
            .each(function (index, element) {
            var thisElem = $(element),
                thisElemAttr = thisElem.attr('data-value');
            // 2. for each item which does not contain a marker yet, apply one    
            if (thisElemAttr.indexOf(mode.substring(0, 1)) === -1) {
                thisElem.attr('data-value', (thisElemAttr += ' ' + mode));
            }
        });
    }
};

prepareData("week");
prepareData("month");

$("#today").on("click", function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var dateValue = date.getDate().toString() + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getFullYear().toString();

    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date);

    $container.isotope({
        filter: '[data-value~="' + dateValue + '"]'
    });
});


$("#week").on("click", function () {
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '[data-value ~="week"]'
    });
});

$("#month").on("click", function () {
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '[data-value ~="month"]'
    });
});
```

As you can see, all the dates in the `data-value` are successfully styled in the date picker, but due to the date format it's also styling the 1st — 9th August too. Is there anyway for both the filter function and beforeShowDay function to work without this problem?
& yes, changing the date format to e.g. `21082013` does solve the `beforeShowDay` styling issue, but breaks the filter function, they both need to work. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using * selector in your `beforeShowDay` function

```
('[data-value*="' + target + '"]')
```

That is why 1st August got styled - because it matches "2182013" value.
Change it to a words selector ~

```
('[data-value~="' + target + '"]')
```

Comment: thank you so much for that, can't believe it was something so small, I've been wracking my brain all day over than one, ha!